# Calculate matrices $[f]_{CB}, [f]_{DC}, [f]_{CC}$ (explaining procedure)

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

We have 3 basis:[image]

and $[-]_{CB}:Hom_k(V,W) -> Mat_k(m*n)$ and analogous for DC and CC

I want to find $[f]_{CB}, [f]_{DC}, [f]_{CC}$ for linear transformatin $f: K^3 -> K^3$

We know, that [image]

**My attempt**:

Let's begin with $[f]_{CB}$. First of all we perform linear transformation w.r.t basis B: $[f]_{CB} = ([f(b_1)]_c, [f(b_2)]_c,[f(b_3)]_c) = [(0,2,0)_c, (0,0,3)_c, (\alpha,1,0)_c)$

But Id don't understand what should we do next. Can you explain me step by step this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write 
$\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\0\end{pmatrix}$,
$\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\3\end{pmatrix}$,
and
$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ in terms of $c_1,c_2,c_3$.

In a more general problem you would have to solve equations like
$$x\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
+y\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}
+z\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$
for $x,y,z$ using Gauss elimination or whatever.

But here we can just spot the answers:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\0\end{pmatrix}=
(-2)\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
+2\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}
+0\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
and so we have that
$$[f]_{CB}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & . & .\\
2 & . & .\\
0 & . & .\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where I leave you to work out the second and third columns in the same way.

Comment: I got the idea, thank you:)